# Puppeteer не реагирует на редирект из за асинхронной функции

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Puppeteer не реагирует на редирект из за асинхронной функции `permissionsTest`, если вернуть просто значение из данной функции все работает. В чем может быть проблема?

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({dumpio: true});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const response = await page.goto('http://localhost:8001');
  const [, page2] = await browser.pages();
  console.log(page2.url());

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Код на странице - `http://localhost:8001`

```js
const tests = [
  permissionsTest,
];

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {

  await analyze();

  window.location.href = 'https://google.com';
});

async function analyze() {
  let br = 0;

  for (let test of tests) {
    br += await test();
  }

  return br;
}

async function permissionsTest() {
  let permissionStatus = await navigator.permissions.query({name: 'notifications'});

  if (Notification.permission === 'denied' && permissionStatus.state === 'prompt') {
    return 20;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: как ты проверяешь реагируемость?

Comment: @Grundy, `console.log(page2.url())` - когда функция `permissionsTest` возвращает просто значение, результат ссылка которая указана в `window.location.href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что **Puppeteer** не дожидался выполнения асинхронных скриптов на странице.

Решилась добавлением опции `waitUntil`.

```
await page.goto('http://localhost:8001', { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
```